# Some Questions about GC and DisplayCompositor

Tags: garbage-collection, chromium, v8

I have some conceptual questions about Chromium. I would appreciate it if you help me.

1. Garbage Collection except V8 & Blink?

   I know that Blink has 'Oilpan' Garbage Collector and V8 has another GC mechanism.

   (Maybe they'll be integrated to 'Unified GC'.)

   But how about the Browser process, Renderer compositor thread and GPU, etc?

   Is there any GC mechanism for them?

   - Unified GC: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CukfHGuadc&amp=&index=26&amp=&list=PL9ioqAuyl6UJ2KrDYYQwdHfmi28PeLQJS&amp=&t=0s
   - V8 Orinoco GC project: https://v8.dev/blog/trash-talk

---

2. I know that the compositing(?) part of Browser process is being transferred to 'Viz' service.

   But It seems to be experimental feature. So the Question is

   - Which thread is the DisplayCompositor(which aggregates CompositorFrames) lives in now?
     I/O Thread of the Browser process?

Sincerely,

Comment: I think you should ask separate questions separately. Also, for questions about any given software project's under-the-hood design choices and development status, that project's community / mailing-list / bug tracker might be a better avenue than SO.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, jmrk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for danakj@chromium.org

1. Outside for blink/v8 renderer code we use explicit malloc/free. I don't know of any GC usage in the browser or gpu process, no.
2. As the text in about:flags says, the display compositor is in the gpu process (on a compositor thread). It is not in the browser process.
   This has been enabled on most platforms now, so I think experimental is not the correct qualifier at this point. :)